# Setting linux (BASH) environment variable with multiple values and export as per requirement

Tags: bash, environment-variables

I am trying to set a variable that should switch (export) as per requirement any inputs, new to shell.
I tried

```
setenv G=1:2

if [[  G == 1 ]]; then
    export ABC='my-name'
elif [[ G == 2 ]]; then
    export ABC='my-emp_id'
else
    export ABC='my-mail'
fi
```

When I give `set G=1` it should `export ABC=my-name`, and similarly when I `set G=2` it should `export ABC=my-emp_id`.

Comment: To compare a variable's value, use a dollar sign in front of the name, e.g., `$G`. Your current code just compares constants ("G" and 1 in the `if`, and so on). https://shellcheck.net would have pointed that out for you.

Comment: Thanks for that Robert... 
I had added $G, but the query is I am trying to export same variable with two different values and that too one at a time as per requirement.
I added above code in my .bashrc it didn't worked..

Comment: To debug, put `set -x` in front of your statements and `set +x` after and see what comes out. It will show you the exact commands the shell is executing between these too commands.